# Apache does not generate a 404

Tags: php, apache, http-status-code-404

if I have `/faq.php` on the server it can also be accessed via `/faq.php/nonexistant.gif` why? I have made sure MultiViews are disabled. Why does the contents of `/faq.php` get shown when I  access the URI `/faq.php/randomstuff.gif`? FYI, I have no htaccess file in the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is called `path_info`. You can disable it using `AcceptPathInfo Off` in the apache config. People generally use it as a fake mod rewrite when mod rewrite is not availalble.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo

Answer (score 2):

`/nonexistant.gif` will be HTTP "PATH_INFO": http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875, section 4.1.5

Basically, the webserver will scan "down" a url until it hits an actual file. Anything after that file in the url becomes PATH_INFO.

```
http://example.com/some/path/leading/to/realfile.php/extra/stuff/that/becomes/path/info
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- real directories
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^--actual file, scanning stops here
                                                    ^^-----onwards = path_info
```